# Regular expression not working in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to set up a regular expression to redirect users to the url fieldguide/0e should they put anything other than 0e or 0E as the first two characters after the URL. The following is in my urls.py file:

```
url(r'^fieldguide/(?P<IDmatch>0[eE]([0-9A-Fa-f]{0,14}))/$', 'treeView', name='index'),
url(r'^fieldguide/./$', 'treeDirect', name='index'),
url(r'^fieldguide/(?!0[Ee]$)/$', 'treeDirect', name='index'),
```

The first handles when the user puts the correct format into the URL, this works fine.
The 2nd handles when the user only puts one character. Also works fine.
The 3rd is where I'm having trouble, I have tried many permutations of this (enclosing in parentheses, without the $, etc.) but none of them seem to work. Can anyone tell me how I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django [doesn't support verbose regexes](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9123) - i.e. '(?x)' - because they make it really difficult to determine the url for a view (as opposed to a view from a url).

The good news is that Django urls are designed to cascade, so you can just do something like the following:

```
url(r'^fieldguide/(?P<IDmatch>0[eE]([0-9A-Fa-f]{0,14}))/$', 'treeView', name='index'),
url(r'^fieldguide/.*$', 'treeDirect', name='index-redirect'),
```